# asyncio post requests with login to site

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio

I'm currently working on a script that firstly bypass the cloudflare with cfscrape and then makes 2 post requests with the payload to log in to the site. I'm getting some errors with the future1 and future2 post. Here is my code:

```
import asyncio
import requests
import cfscrape

async def main():
s = requests.Session()
s.get('https://www.off---white.com/en/IT')

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.off---white.com/it/IT/login',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
    }

payload1 = {
    'spree_user[email]': 'email',
    'spree_user[password]': 'password',
    'spree_user[remember_me]': '0',
}

payload2 = {
    'spree_user[email]': 'email',
    'spree_user[password]': 'password',
    'spree_user[remember_me]': '0',
}

scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper(s)
scraper.get('https://www.off---white.com/en/IT', headers=headers)
print('Done')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
print('Starting loop')

future1 = loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.post ,'https://www.off---white.com/it/IT/login', data=payload1, headers=headers)
future2 = loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.post ,'https://www.off---white.com/it/IT/login', data=payload2, headers=headers)
response1 = await future1
response2 = await future2
print(response1.text)
print(response2.text)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Error:

```
File "async_amatriciana.py", line 41, in <module>
loop.run_until_complete(main())
File "lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py" line 468, in 
run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "async_amatriciana.py", line 33, in main
future1 = loop.run_in_executor(None, requests.post ,'https://www.off--- 
white.com/it/IT/login', data=payload1, headers=headers)
TypeError: run_in_executor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'
```

Comment: What are the errors? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53020839/edit) your question to include them. Also, you can’t use `await` outside of a coroutine defined with `async def`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor(executor, callback, *args)

I ran your code and got lots of erros , therefore i rewrite your code.You need to know follow those

1. use `cfscrape` to post data instead of `requests` , unless you add cookies into your post request
2. `await` must inside `async def`
3. `run_in_executor` only get `args` not `kwargs`
4. Rule # 9: don’t use `requests` in async code -- from @Brad Solomon

The rewrote code

```
import asyncio
import requests
import cfscrape

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.off---white.com/it/IT/login',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
    }

payload1 = {
    'spree_user[email]': 'email',
    'spree_user[password]': 'password',
    'spree_user[remember_me]': '0',
}

payload2 = {
    'spree_user[email]': 'email',
    'spree_user[password]': 'password',
    'spree_user[remember_me]': '0',
}


def post(dict):
    scraper = cfscrape.create_scraper(requests.Session())
    req = scraper.post(**dict)
    return req

async def get_data():
    datas = [dict(url='https://www.off---white.com/it/IT/login', data=payload1, headers=headers),
            dict(url='https://www.off---white.com/it/IT/login', data=payload2, headers=headers)]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    response = [loop.run_in_executor(None, post , data) for data in datas]
    result = await asyncio.gather(*response)
    print(result)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(get_data())
```

Comment: @BradSolomon the the most difficulty is off-white have cloudflare ,  and you are right `requests` is block-module

Comment: But it is a multiple-threads when using `run_in_executor`. I think it was not wrong , just like running blocking function on tornado

Comment: Thanks to all, in the end I've chosen to make my script with threads instead going with asyncio.

Comment: @ChefTraian  In your code , you are using threads too. But this is type of `Concurrent.future`.